# Unity3d MacOs fullscrean scroll does not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, fullscreen

I am using Unity3d.

Scrolling in Full screen does not work on mac os but working on Windows machine.
What wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and scrolling works just fine. Send a bug report to Unity via Help->Report a bug if you continue to have issues.